# Create a reusable array

Tags: arrays, swift

In my networking model, either I have to create few function for fetching data or using one single function to handle everything. I want to do the second way.

For example in the function, I add a switch to change data

```
Let request : Request
Var dataModel : ...


Switch type {
 Case type1:
    request = ....
    dataModel = [String]
 Case type2:
    request = ....
    dataModel = [TaskDataModel]
}

 request.execute( dataModel.self, request: request) { result in
```

As you can see, I can do it with `Request`, but there will be some array of models, they can be simple like that

```
dataModel = [String]
```

Or

```
 dataModel = [TaskDataModel]
```

Could anyone help that how I can create a reusable array to can be changes to anything in the switch?

Many thanks

Comment: It looks like *Generics* could be suitable

Comment: Could you give me a simple example? Many thanks

Comment: Please read [Generics](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) in the Language Guide.

Comment: Can you show the current, repetitive code that you want to refactor? I don't see how the `dataModel = ...` line relates to the switch statement.

Comment: @Sweeper please check the first post, I updated it

Comment: Let's suppose you _can_ do that. Since you don't know the type of `dataModel` at compile time (you only know its type when you run the switch), you can't really do anything useful with it, can you?

Comment: This is in the function, and when I call this function, I select the type and the switch will run in any way